# Removing node from Dynamically linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes, singly-linked-list

I am writing a program that saves strings into a linked list while allocating memory for both the string and the node. I have my insert and search functions working perfectly but I can't seem to get my delete function working. It doesn't seem to remove the information from the node but I am at a loss for what the set to what and what to free. Any help would be more than welcome even if it is just a hint.

My node and list struct

```
typedef struct listNode {               //simple linked list   structure
struct listNode *next;                  //address to next
char *data;                            //data
} NODE;

typedef struct ListStruct {
   NODE *head;                         //head node for iterating
} LIST;
```

This is my current nonworking version of deleting a node

```
void deleteNode(LIST *list, char *string){          // passed linked list and string to find
NODE *prev, *curr, *temp;                       //variables init
//int compare;                              // for strcmp if needed
prev = NULL;                                //set prev to null
curr = list->head;                          //set current to the head of the list
while(curr != NULL){                            //while the current node is not null
if(strcmp(curr->data,string) == 0){         //check for the proper string 
    temp = curr;                            //set temp to current node to be deleted
    temp->data = strcpy(curr->data);        //copy data so free is possible
    prev->next = temp;                     //set the prev to temp
    free(curr->data);                      //free malloc'd data
    free(curr);                           //free malloc'd node
    curr = temp;                          //set curr back to temp
}
else{                               //if string isn't found at current
    prev = curr;                        //set previous to current
    curr = curr->next;                  //and current to current.next
}   

}
}//done
```

I know that the error is when I find the proper string but I can't for the life of me figure out what is wrong. Hope to hear from someone soon and thank you as always.

Comment: I would recommend to make the functions a bit more modular. Meaning the search and compare part as one function, that would return a NODE.
Then the delete would just take as an argument a NODE, and free it's string and the NODE itself.
And by so making it more debuggable, maintainable and easier to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to update the if block a little bit:

```
if(strcmp(curr->data,string) == 0){         //check for the proper string 
  temp = curr;                            //set temp to current node to be deleted
  if (prev == NULL)                         // if the first node is the one to be deleted
    list->head = curr->next;
  else
    prev->next = curr->next;                //set prev next pointer to curr next node
  curr = curr->next;                      //curr updated
  free(temp->data);                      //free malloc'd data
  free(temp);                           //free malloc'd node

  break;   //assume there is only one unique string in the link list
}
```

Comment: One correction: it should be `list->head` instead of `list->header`.

Comment: Still not working but I will work with this and some printf's and see if I can get her working. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Chris, please provide some output which might be helpful to debug.

Comment: @Dere0405 I'm kind of embarrassed to say, but I forgot to uncomment my line  calling the function, it works amazing. I really appreciate the help.